# Menu disappears on small screens

Tags: 7, theming

On [this site](http://p262957.mittwaldserver.info/drupal/) I implemented the [Multi Level Push Menu](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/). All works fine, but the menu disappears on small screens (tablet width and below). I use Bootstrap 3 und Drupal 7 in this project.

I already tried it with increasing the `z-index` on `#menu`, but it didn't worked.

I'm thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu/issues/134#issuecomment-164296107) the problem, was that a div container pushed the menu away.

The old and wrong container was:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="content-container" style="
display: table-cell;">
```

It could be fixed by adding additional bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="content-container">
```

Comment: When you answer your own question it is customary to accept it as the answer so that it doesn't continue to appear in the unanswered list. Thanks!

Comment: yeah i tried, but stack systems says that this is only allowed two days after submission of the answer, so we have to wait one more day :)

Comment: ok lol sounds good!